# Google App Script no Google Calc - Célula usando função importada não atualiza seu valor

Tags: google-sheets

Tenho várias planilhas do google (Google Calc) usando um script feito no Google App Script como biblioteca. O problema é que as células que se utilizam dessas funções importadas não atualizam seus valores quando o script importado sofre alterações.

Para exemplificar, no script feito no Google App Script tenho o seguinte código:

```js
//Código do script (biblioteca que foi importada)
function operando(x,y){
  return x + y;
}
```

Já na planilha que importa esse script como biblioteca eu tenho o seguinte código:

```js
//Código no Google App Script da planilha
//A biblioteca foi importada com o nome de lib
//Esse código é necessário para eu ter acesso a função importada a partir de uma célula
function operando(x,y){
  return lib.operando(x,y);
}
```

Se eu digitar "=operando(2,3)" numa célula, ele me retornará o valor 5 como esperado.

O problema é quando eu altero o código do script que foi importado:

```js
//Código do script alterado (biblioteca que foi importada)
function operando(x,y){
  return x * y;
}
```

A célula deveria atualizar seu valor para 6, mas continua mostrando o valor 5.
Se eu digitar em outra célula a mesma fórmula com os mesmos argumentos, ele me retorna o 6 esperado.

Existe alguma forma de contornar esse problema?